# Removing bytecode instructions from within a method using ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have been using ASM to dynamically manipulate classes as they are loaded. I need the ability to remove bytecode instructions (i.e. those specific instructions which I inserted) from within a method using ASM.

Is there any sample program which could help me with this?

More details:
During the first-time bytecode injection, below is the AdviceAdapter instruction. Subsequently, during re-transformation, I need to remove these instructions.

```
   protected void onMethodEnter(){
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);

    mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "org/agent/trace/RootTracer", "pojoMethodBegin", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
    mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);
}

protected void onMethodExit(int opcode){
    if(opcode!=ATHROW) {
        onFinally(opcode);
    }
}

private void onFinally(int opcode){
    if(opcode == ATHROW){
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "org/agent/trace/RootTracer", "recordException", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    }

    mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, okFlag);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(opcode);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "org/agent/trace/RootTracer", "pojoMethodEnd", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)V");
}
```

Comment: Are you using the tree API or the visitor API?

Comment: @immibis, I am using the ASM visitor API

Comment: You simply don't pass those instructions to the parent visitor.